# In RHEL 8, Tomcat fails to start if try to serve a directory (outside webapps) as context in server.xml

Tags: tomcat, redhat, rhel, tomcat9

I followed the guide from Internet to setup tomcat to start as service using

1. systemctl start tomcat.service
   (using tomcat as a owner, I guess). When I try to deploy one of the app hrmis in tomcat manager GUI, it reports the following error

FAIL - Application at context path [/hrmis] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@13eb8acf]]

The content of the /usr/local/tomcat9/conf/Catalina/localhost/hrmix.xml is

```
 <Context docBase="/home/hrmis/develop/HRMIS2_DEV/WebRoot" />
```

2. The funny thing is when I start tomcat as a root by running command ./startup.sh (as a root), tomcat even automatically deploys the context
3. in order to avoid the permission problem (or just for testing purpose), I already make everything in /home/hrmis/develop/HRMIS2_DEV/WebRoot 777 permission (owner and group are still "tomcat" though)

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

The Tomcat user will need at least read and execute permissions on each directory in the path `/home/hrmis/develop/HRMIS2_DEV/WebRoot`.

Comment: But I have already make the directory
 (/home/hrmis/develop/HRMIS2_DEV/WebRoot) and the files inside having read and execute permission (actually all permission 777 to all groups) (Though I don't intend to do that in the long run. I am just testing as I suspected it has to do with user permission reason). 
The directory looks like it.
'code'
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 tomcat tomcat   361 5月  13 14:16  .tomcatplugin 
drwxrwxrwx. 11 tomcat tomcat  4096 6月  28 23:42  WebRoot   
drwxrwxrwx. 12 tomcat tomcat   219 6月  27 18:33  Websvr   
drwxrwxrwx.  3 tomcat tomcat    17 6月  27 18:33  work

Comment: The Tomcat user still needs at least read and execute permission on every directory in the path.